# Replace 1 value in a subsection of dataframe with value of another column

Tags: python, pandas, one-hot-encoding

I have a one hot encoded dataframe such as:

```
|  qtd|   a |   b |  c |   d |  e | ...z|
|-----+-----+-----|----|----+-----+-----|
|  90 |   1 |   0 |  0 |   0 |  0 |   0 |
|  10 |   0 |   0 |  0 |   0 |  0 |   1 |
|  40 |   0 |   1 |  0 |   0 |  0 |   0 |
|  80 |   0 |   0 |  1 |   0 |  0 |   0 |
|  90 |   0 |   1 |  0 |   0 |  0 |   0 |
```

I want to replace the values of the columns `a` to infinite with the value in `qtd` where the column has 1 as value, there is only one 1 value in the `a` to infinite dataframe subframe.

Such as:

```
|  qtd|   a |   b |  c |   d |  e | ...z|
|-----+-----+-----|----|----+-----+-----|
|  90 |  90 |   0 |  0 |   0 |  0 |   0 |
|  10 |   0 |   0 |  0 |   0 |  0 |  10 |
|  40 |   0 |  40 |  0 |   0 |  0 |   0 |
|  80 |   0 |   0 | 80 |   0 |  0 |   0 |
|  90 |   0 |  90 |  0 |   0 |  0 |   0 |
```

Comment: So you want `np.where()`. Presumably you did your research and something didn;t work out; what was the issue?

Comment: The problem with using np.where() was that there are multiple columns that I need to do that so using where seems very inefficient since I would need to loop through a lot of columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can select all columns without first by [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) and multiple by column with [`DataFrame.mul`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mul.html):

```
df.iloc[:, 1:] = df.iloc[:, 1:].mul(df['qtd'], axis=0)
print (df)
   qtd   a   b   c  d  e   z
0   90  90   0   0  0  0   0
1   10   0   0   0  0  0  10
2   40   0  40   0  0  0   0
3   80   0   0  80  0  0   0
4   90   0  90   0  0  0   0
```

If column is not always first is possible get columns names by [`Index.difference`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.difference.html) and select by subset:

```
cols = df.columns.difference(['qtd'])
df[cols] = df[cols].mul(df['qtd'], axis=0)
```

If first column is index:

```
df = df.mul(df.index, axis=0)
print (df)
      a   b   c  d  e   z
qtd                      
90   90   0   0  0  0   0
10    0   0   0  0  0  10
40    0  40   0  0  0   0
80    0   0  80  0  0   0
90    0  90   0  0  0   0
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is `numpy` broadcast way

```
df.values[:,1:]*=df.qtd[:,None]
df
Out[461]: 
   qtd   a   b   c  d  e   z
0   90  90   0   0  0  0   0
1   10   0   0   0  0  0  10
2   40   0  40   0  0  0   0
3   80   0   0  80  0  0   0
4   90   0  90   0  0  0   0
```